# Xcode 5 How to turn app into Newsstand app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, newsstand-kit

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/). I added "Application presents content in newsstand = true" to Info.plist as well as Newsstand icon:

[image: Info.plist]

But my app appears in simulator as regular app and not in Newsstand. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know, if I should remove this question, but I figured that resetting the simulator solves the problem